# Checkout specific release code for chromium

Tags: git, build, chromium

Using the [newGit](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/wiki/UsingNewGit) checkout for google-chromium code, it asks me to set the remote repository to [this](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src.git). Now when I go to the source code, I only see trunk branch over there. I need to checkout a specific previous version. How to checkout that? One solution might be to check the logs and then revert back to that, but this can be a mess if I want to check out a version released a year back. 
So how to find that revision of the chromium code?

Comment: i found out that currently (14 March 2013), they don't support checking out specific release via newGit method. _Sad_ but true.

Answer (score 0):

You can use git-svn to check out a specific release. Note, however, that the git hashes won't match the hashes in the existing chromium git mirror. Chromium only tracks master in git; Chromium releases are usually partway down SVN "branches." See https://code.google.com/p/chromium/wiki/UsingGit#Working_with_release_branches